# How to linkify urls in a string with php?

Tags: php, regex, yii

I have the following strings having pattern which given below:

```
1)click on http://www.google.com

2) click onhttp://www.google.com".

3) click on www.google.com

4) click onwww.google.com

5) click on www.google.com#xyz

6) click onwww.google.com#xyz
```

I need to convert all these string to below manner with using of regular expression:

```
click on <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">http://www.google.com</a>

click onhttp://www.google.com

click on <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">www.google.com</a>

click onwww.google.com

click on <a href="http://www.google.com#xyz" target="_blank">www.google.com#xyz</a>

click onwww.google.com
```

Comment: So `click on` becomes `Look on` and the URL is clickable?

Comment: I want suggestion for second one also.

Comment: @AbhishekKasera I've edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26774893/3000179) to include `target="_blank"`. Is there anything I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

```
function linkify( $string ) {
    return preg_replace( "~\bhttp(s)?://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]\b~", "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $string);
}
```

https://eval.in/218437

Comment: its work for https but not work when url contains www ie. "onwww.example.com"

Comment: Oh, you've updated the question.

Comment: yes, add all requirement, so please suggest me solution for that

Comment: Well, it's not clear how you decide how a legitimate third-level domains look like. onwww.somesite.com is a valid domain name, and strictly speaking is not a URL (since there is no schema).

Answer (score -2):

You could use something like;

```
/\s((http(s)?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.)(com|org|net|mil|edu|))/i
```

With a replace of

```
<a href="$2">$2<a/>
```

http://regex101.com/r/nI4gU6/7

Which would make your PHP something like;

```
 $str = preg_replace(
            '/\s((http(s)?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.)(com|org|net|mil|edu))/i',
            ' <a href="${1}" target="_blank">${1}</a>', 
             $s);
```

For example: https://eval.in/218269

(**Note:** You'd need to modify it to allow [all the other (g)TLD's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) - however the basic set-up is there)

Comment: There are a lot of new top level domain names...

Answer (score -3):

You could have something like this:

```
<?php
 function addhttp($url) {
   if (false === strpos($url, '://')) {
      $url = 'http://' . $url;
   }
   return $url;
 }

 $url = "www.google.com";

 var_dump(addhttp($url)); 
 ?>
```

Then for the URLS where you want to output "http://" you just pass it to the function.

Output: http://codepad.org/MlvXWRR2

Comment: @downvoter - Why the downvote with no explanation? Seems stupid.

Comment: Adding `http://` doesn't automatically make the link clickable.

Comment: Wow I did not add `<a href...>` again, stupid reason. No offence

Comment: plz, suggest me solution... question is updated now