# Anchor tag setup for given string with php

Tags: php, regex

I have the following strings:

```
1)search #test

2)search https://example.com/search#test".

3)searchhttps://example.com#test"
```

I need to convert it to:

first one like

```
search <a href="https://example.com/search?q=test" target="_blank">#test</a>
```

second one should be simple url -

```
search <a href="https://example.com/search#test" target="_blank">https://example.com#test</a>
```

third one should be remain same

```
searchhttps://example.com#test"
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: I want add HTML anchor tag in string in specific condition where string contains hash tag.

Comment: Same author duplicate of [How to linkify urls in a string with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774799/how-to-linkify-urls-in-a-string-with-php)

Comment: please, check first, these are two different requirement. same pattern is not working for those. Thants why I asked in different question.

Answer (score 0):

1st

```
$pattern = '/search\s(#)+(.+)/';
$string = "search #test";
$string = preg_replace($pattern, 'search <a href="https://example.com/search?q=\2" target="_blank">https://example.com#\2</a>', $string);
echo $string;
```

2nd

```
$pattern = '/search\s(http(s)*(.*))(#)+(.+)/';
$string = "search https://example.com/search#test";
$string = preg_replace($pattern, 'search <a href="https://example.com/search#\5" target="_blank">#\5</a>', $string);
echo $string;
```

Simply apply the first one, and then the second one to the text you want to process.

```
$pattern = '/search\s(#)+(.+)/';
    $string = "whateveryouwant";
    $string = preg_replace($pattern, 'search <a href="https://example.com/search?q=\2" target="_blank">https://example.com#\2</a>', $string);


    $pattern = '/search\s(http(s)*(.*))(#)+(.+)/';
    $string = preg_replace($pattern, 'search <a href="https://example.com/search#\5" target="_blank">#\5</a>', $string);
```

**EDIT**

2nd case, generic url

```
 $pattern = '/search\s(http(s)*(.*))(#)+(.+)/';
        $string = preg_replace($pattern, 'search <a href="\1#\5" target="_blank">#\5</a>', $string);
```

For the first case, no url can be recognized.

Comment: It work for specific pattern of url so please suggest me regular expression for any type of url.

Comment: For the 2nd case, replace  https://example.com/search with \1 For the 1st one, no way.